# Linked Lists: Iterator vs List Iterator

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator

I'm reviewing linked lists in Java, learned them in C, and I noticed that I can use an iterator class to go through the linked list. But what I found strange is that they used a ListIterator to iterate forwards on the list (it can also be used to iterate backwards depending on where the pointer is), and Iterator to iterate backwards on the list. My question is, why can't we just use Iterator to iterate both forwards and backwards? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: `listIterator` adds multiple methods to move around the datastructure you're iterating

Comment: I can't tell where you are looking, but `DescendingIterator` actually implements `Iterator` and uses `ListItr` internally which in turn is used when iterating forward. Or did I miss your question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Iterator

`Iterator` is a **very general solution** which should fit **all data-structures**, in fact you can iterate **every** class in `Collection` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)). But not every class there can ensure backwards-iterating simply due to their internal data-structure. For example a `TreeSet` which only knows its **root** element:

[image: TreeSet structure]

So `Iterator` tries to fit the common ability of all data structures to be at least iterable in **one direction** ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html))

---

### ListIterator

`ListIterator` is a **special**, not general, **solution** only useable for special `List` since they can, due to their internal structure, be iterated in both directions (and also allow adding and removing elements in between). This is not possible with other structures like `TreeSet`, so `Collection` doesn't offer `ListIterator` for all `Collection`s, just `List` has it. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list in either direction, modify the list during iteration, and obtain the iterator's current position in the list.

---

To wrap it up, if `Collection` would offer a special `Iterator` like `ListIterator` then all implementing classes, also `TreeSet` and co. would need to implement this method. However those classes may not be able to meet that requirement (without heavy extra overhead).

Answer (score 1):

[From the API:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list in either direction, modify the list during iteration, and obtain the iterator's current position in the list.

Conversely, an `Iterator` [can only iterate forwards.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)